# Why do I get a compiler error when including <string.h> and using std::basic_string?

Tags: c++, stdstring

When i try to compile the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
typedef std::basic_string<char> foostring;
foostring foo = "foo";
```

I get the following error:

```
stringtest.cpp:5: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
stringtest.cpp:6: error: ‘foostring’ does not name a type
```

My compiler is: g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1
What am i doing wrong? i intend to use this with windows TCHAR for unicode support once i figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header is `<string>`, not `<string.h>`.

None of the standard library headers end with an extension. (You're including the C header `string.h`, which should be included in C++ via `<cstring>`, had that been what you actually wanted.)